# Display divs as table in php while loop

Tags: php, css, loops

I have a paginator class in which I loop through the results from an article database.

```
$html = '<div class="library-main-panel">' . "\n";
                
                while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                    $id = $result["id"];
                    
                    $html .= '<div class="article-intro-panel">' . "\n";
                    $headline = $result["headline"];
                    $author = $result["author"];
                    $description = $result["description"];
                    
                    $html .= '<p class="intro-headline">' . 
                    $headline . '</p>' . "\n" .
                    '<p>' . 'Skriven av ' . $author . '</p>' . "\n";
                    
                    if (strlen($description) !== 0) {
                            
                        $html .= '<p>' . $description . '</p>' . "\n";  
                        
                    }
                    
                    $html .= '<p>' . '<a href="index.php?' . 
                    'page=article&num=' . $id . '" target="_top">' . 
                    'L&auml;s mer' . '</a>' . '</p>' . "\n";
                                        
                    $html .= '</div>' . "\n";                   
                    
                }
                
                $html .= '</div>' . "\n";
                
                echo $html;
```

I want to design the divs in the loop as a HTML-table with header, rows and columns. My CSS is good but I am uncertain on how this would be done in the real world. Any help or hint are greatly appreciated. I should point out that I don't want to use css-table code.

Comment: It looks as though your data might be tabular and you mention an HTML table. Is there a reason you are using div elements rather than creating an HTML table element with rows and cells?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you would be told to use div rows and columns.  The only reason I can think of is to make breaks after some many records.
So I'm assume if you have 100 records and 5 columns you calculate the number of row in a column to get the number of rows in each of the 5 columns.
Some one may believe that it is more difficult to break into columns if you are using a table.

But it is routine to break a table in multiple columns.
Here is some code where I broke a table in to 3 columns one the fly.
This table shows if someone is allergic to Dust Mites (D. farine) what other allergens they are most likely to be allergic to based on 100,000 patients and 2,000,000 allergen test results. Immunology is a hobby of mine.  I like to do analytics. I wrote this app for myself, that's why it has very little styling.

Here the table is being broken into a new column.  Each table has float left.  Very simple.

```
$rows++;
if($rows == 34 OR $rows == 67){
  echo "</table><table>\n<tr><td></td><td> Allergen</td><td class=\"center\">Class<br>0</td><td class=\"center\">Class<br>1+</td><td>Class<br>Sum</td><td>Class<br>Avg</td></tr>\n";
}
```

Below is the three tables.  The values were fixed because I put a limit on how many records to show. In your case they would be calculated values.

[image]

I would have been nice if you had posted the html that is generated. Your style of creating strings is a bit cumbersome.

Using HEREDOC  `echo <<<EOT` in your echo which makes all this so much easier.  It terminates with `EOT;` and on it own line by itself.  You do not have to use EOT you can use any value. Fro me EOT means End Of Text.

First off the is a much better way to do this:

```
$headline = $result["headline"];
$author = $result["author"];
$description = $result["description"];
```

I do this sort of thing all the time so I'm going to show how I do it. 
If I understand correctly you want to use a `<table>`.  In this case tables are a good way to go because the table will optimize the column widths.
The character set is important for correct rendering.  It better you set rather the Browser waste time trying and determine what character set you are using.

Using HEREDOC  `echo <<<EOT` in your echo which makes all this so much easier.  It terminates with `EOT;` and on it own line by itself.  You do not have to use EOT you can use any value. Fro me EOT means End Of Text.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=120');
echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title>Articles</title>
<style>
</style>
</head><body>
<div class="library-main-panel">
<table>
<caption>Table Header</caption>
<tr><td>Headline</td><td>Author</td><td>Description</td><td>Link</td><tr>
EOT;

$sql = "SELECT `headline,`author`,`description` FROM table WHERE 1";
$results = myusqli_query($link,$sql);
while(list($headline,$author,$description) =  mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM)){
  echo "<tr><td>$headline</td><td>$author</td><td>$description</td><td><form action=\"#\" method=\"get\"><button>L&auml;s mer'<button></form></td><tr>\n";
}
echo '</table></div></body></html>';
?>
```

There's more you can do for the styling.

This is an app I did for an allergy testing lab
This is a case were I do things  on the fly. 
When an allergist is order the allergens to be tested for the patient they often (most of the time) use panels of tests. This here when the doc clicks on the light blue button it reveals which allergen are in the test panel.  There are three types of allergen antibodies that the lab can test, E,G, and G4.  I color code the three types.  The green background means that food the patient eats often.  
The panel tests are in a table.

[image]

I do my queries at and build a "panel object" with arrays.  So here I am just showing how to format the HTML table cells.

There is one line of code that echos the row it's this one.

```
echo $typeE[$types[1]] . $typeG4[$types[3]] . $typeG[$types[2]] . $match[$types[0]] . "<td class=\"ptext\">$rast[$code]</td></tr>\n";

foreach($panels as $pdx => $panel){
  $matches = $panels[$pdx][3][5];
  $countTests = $panels[$pdx][3][0];
  $countIgE = $panels[$pdx][3][1];
  $countIgG = $panels[$pdx][3][2];
  $countIgG4 = $panels[$pdx][3][3];
  if($pdx == 200){
  echo <<<EOT
<p class="bold">What the numbers mean:</p>
<div class="matches"> </div> number of foods that match what the patient eats often<br>
<div class="countIgE"> </div> number of IgE tests
<div class="countIgG4"> </div> number of IgG<sub>4</sub> tests<br>
<div class="countIgG"> </div> number of IgG tests
<div class="countTests"> </div> total number of tests<br>
</div>
</div><button id="c30" class="link" type="button" onclick ="expb('30')">Allermetrix Panels</button>

<div id="e30" class="expand">

EOT;
  }
  echo "<div><input id=\"c$pdx\" type=\"checkbox\"  name=\"P" .  $panels[$pdx][1]  . "\" value=\"" . $panels[$pdx][2] . "\" />&#x2003;<div class=\"pname\"  onclick =\"exp('$pdx')\"><div class=\"click\" >$panel[1] $panel[2]&#x2003;</div></div><div class=\"matches\">$matches</div><div class=\"countIgE\"> $countIgE</div><div class=\"countIgG4\"> $countIgG4</div><div class=\"countIgG\"> $countIgG</div><div class=\"countTests\">$countTests</div></div>" . $TIgE[$panels[$pdx][6]] . "\n<div id=\"e$pdx\" class=\"texp\"><table>\n";
  foreach($panel[4] as $code => $types){
    echo $typeE[$types[1]] . $typeG4[$types[3]] . $typeG[$types[2]] . $match[$types[0]] . "<td class=\"ptext\">$rast[$code]</td></tr>\n";
  }
echo <<<EOT
</table>

</div>
EOT;
}
```

**This may be what you are looking for.**
[image]

These are rows with divs as columns. 
This is the HTML:
br>

```
<button id="b0" class="link" name="tab" value="0">Food by Category</button><button id="b1" class="link" name="tab" value="1">Food Alphabetical</button><button id="b2" class="link" name="tab" value="2">Pollen</button><button id="b3" class="link" name="tab" value="3">Environmental</button><button id="b4" class="link" name="tab" value="4">Chemical</button><button id="b5" class="link" name="tab" value="5">Panels</button><button id="b6" class="link" name="tab" value="6">Review</button>

<div class="col">
 <p class="cat">Animal</p>
<div class="row">
<div class="dchk"><label class="e chk"><input type="checkbox" id="F0271" class="chk" name="aF0271" value="1" /><span></span></label></div>
<div class="dchk"><label class="g4 chk"><input type="checkbox" id="F0273" class="chk" name="aF0273" value="3" /><span></span></label></div>
<div class="dchk"><label class="g chk"><input  type="checkbox" id="F0272" class="chk" name="aF0272" value="2" /><span></span></label></div>
<div class="inline">&nbsp;Beef</div></div>
<div class="row">
<div class="dchk"><label class="e chk"><input type="checkbox" id="F0371" class="chk" name="aF0371" value="1" /><span></span></label></div>
<div class="dchk"><label class="g4 chk"><input type="checkbox" id="F0373" class="chk" name="aF0373" value="3" /><span></span></label></div>
<div class="dchk"><label class="g chk"><input  type="checkbox" id="F0372" class="chk" name="aF0372" value="2" /><span></span></label></div>
<div class="inline">&nbsp;Bison</div></div>
<div class="row">
<div class="dchk"><label class="e chk"><input type="checkbox" id="F0831" class="chk" name="aF0831" value="1" /><span></span></label></div>
<div class="dchk"><label class="g4 chk"><input type="checkbox" id="F0833" class="chk" name="aF0833" value="3" /><span></span></label></div>
<div class="dchk"><label class="g chk"><input  type="checkbox" id="F0832" class="chk" name="aF0832" value="2" /><span></span></label></div>
<div class="inline">&nbsp;Chicken</div></div>
```

...

As you see within each row div there are 4 column divs.
Then those rows are contained in a single div  column `<div #col-"col">`

Change the 4 to a 5 and you have 5 columns.

```
col{columns: 4 auto;
margin: 20px 0 0 0;
letter-spacing: -.35px;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply. What I am looking after is a way to split div elements into at least 5 columns with rows. I have seen this before using percentage in the while loop when calculating the amount of columns and rows.

Comment: For this project I have been told not to use html tables for tabular data. I have to split divs into columns and rows using percentage in the while loop.

Comment: Okay I'm done.  I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: @ingmarleifsson I do not understand  percentage.  Percentage of what?

Comment: Something like this in a while loop:  $cols = 4 if ($i % $cols == 0) or something like that. I just need a little kickstart help.

Comment: When you get the zero then you want to start a new row?  You are not giving enough information.  I still have no clue what is you are trying do do.   Do you have anything to show that would be useful?  Like some HTML or a screen shot of the desired result.  Some sort of example.  Even a drawing.   I could guess again but that has not been going well.